# How to decode Date or time string

Tags: php

I am using this function to change date format.

```
   echo date("mdy", strtotime('2013-11-04'));
```

It's return: 110413

Now i want to decode it.

How to get date like this format: 2013-11-04

Remember 110413 should be as a input of that function

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing anything with the date when it is already in the format that you want? You say you want 2013-11-04 and you already have that in your script??

Comment: @Simply
I am using that script to change date format to store in file and now want to revers that script to get result. Here input 2013-11-04 may be anything.

Comment: When you say it may be anything - do you mean the date may be anything or that it may be in any format?

Comment: @Simply
date may be anything not format

Comment: Again though, it is already in the format you need to store so why to you need to change it? For example, if the original date was in the format 04-11-2013, then you would need to change it to 2013-11-04 but you are saying this is not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
$MyDate="110413";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdy',$MyDate); 
echo $newformat=$date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
 $date = date("mdy", strtotime("2013-11-04"));
 $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdy', $date);
 $newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');

 echo $newDateString;
```

Comment: I want to 2013-11-04 not 2013-11-12

Answer (score 1):

```
$mydate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2013-11-04'));
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($mydate));
```